# cakephp how to find a field that is joined by related tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am new to cakephp and having problem in solving the **Class** and **Subject** relations.

I have three tables:

```
**studclass**             **subjectclass**                       **subject**
  id                        id                                     id
  class_name                studclassID(foreignKey)                subject_name
                            subjectID(foreignKey)
```

Relationship:

(Studclass Model)

```
 public $hasMany = array(
        'ClassSubjects' => array(
            'className' => 'SubjectClass',
            'foreignKey' => 'classID',
        )
    );
```

(Subject Model)

```
 public $hasMany = array(
        'SubjectsClass' => array(
            'className' => 'SubjectClass',
            'foreignKey' => 'subjectID',
        )
    );
```

(SubjectClass Model)

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
        'Studclass' => array(
            'className' => 'Studclass',
            'foreignKey' => 'classID'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'className' => 'Subject',
            'foreignKey' => 'subjectID'
        ));
```

Array Generated by **Studclass** View:

```
array(
'Sclass' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'class_name' => 'BCA1'
),
'ClassSubjects' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'subjectID' => '1',
        'classID' => '1'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'subjectID' => '2',
        'classID' => '1'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'subjectID' => '3',
        'classID' => '1'
    )
)
```

)

so what I want is instead of `SubjectID` in **Studclass** view I want to display `subject_name`.....can any one help me how to do that...I am new to cakephp and having hard time dealing with it...Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Have you looked into implementing the [hasAndBelongsToMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) to manage this relationship. I believe its array is more along the lines you want.

Comment: Thank you...i used hasAndBelongsToMany relationship and its worked