# Joining 3 tables in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Using Cakephp 2.5.3 ... I have the following tables:

**transactions** (belongs to methods and deliveries)

- id
- delivery_id
- method_id

**methods** (has many transactions)

- id
- name

**deliveries** (has many transactions)

- id
- date

In my delivery view I would like to see the method name for each delivery.

```
foreach ($deliveries as $delivery) {

echo $method['name'];

}
```

( a similar unanswered question is 
[here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636991/cakephp-how-to-find-a-field-that-is-joined-by-related-tables))

I am (obv.) very new to Cakephp,  What approach should I take to go about this?  Thanks!

=========UPDATE==============

I ended up adding methods to the deliveries controller

```
$this->set('methods', $this->Method->find('all', array('recursive' => -1)));
```

And looped through the methods in my (read only) view :

```
  //filtered method array for
  $method['id'] == $delivery['Transaction']['0']['method_id']) 
   // got method name 
   $button_text = $method['name'];
```

It works fine but can anyone tell me if this may cause problems for me down the line?

Comment: which version of CakePHP?

Comment: So you want to join all the 3 together... 1 transaction has one method and one delivery - which means, delivery and method will have transaction_id .. Please elaborate your question

Comment: Sorry, my title is not very good.  I am thinking of how to re-word it.

Comment: Have you read the book over building a [HasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) association or a [HasManyThrough-join](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)? The way you describe your table it's probably your transaction that leads to delivery and method, so it seems impossible to get from a single delivery to a method without a transaction.

Comment: That looks very promising.  Your answers are making me think I am getting my associations mixed up. the delivery is unique to the transaction but the method is not.

Comment: What does this mean _the delivery is unique to the transaction but the method is not_? Sample data would help to clarify.

Comment: Again I apologize, I am having trouble organizing my thoughts.  Each transaction has one delivery and one method.  Many transactions can have that method_id but no other transaction can have that delivery_id.  Does that make method a habtm association?  I have read every tutorial I can about habtm as well as many to many and it just ain't clicking.

Answer (score 0):

use has many assotiations in `Transaction` model as -

```
public $hasMny = array('Method', 'Delivery');
```

then fetch them -

```
$this->set(
   'methods', 
   $this->Method->find('all', array('contain' => array('Method', 'Delivery')))
);
```

you will get all the related result together.